# retrieves menu and converts it to a readable array

Tags: functions, menus, navigation, sub-menu

I have added this code in function.php to retrieves menu and converts it to a readable array
but It's not working and give me this warning.
Warning
: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
C:\xampp\htdocs\Upwork\wp-content\themes\truckloanhub\functions.php
on line
117

Warning
: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
C:\xampp\htdocs\Upwork\wp-content\themes\truckloanhub\functions.php
on line
127

```
function wp_get_menu_array($current_menu) {



$array_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($current_menu);
   $menu = array();
   foreach ($array_menu as $m) {
       if (empty($m->menu_item_parent)) {
           $menu[$m->ID] = array();
           $menu[$m->ID]['ID']      =   $m->ID;
           $menu[$m->ID]['title']       =   $m->title;
           $menu[$m->ID]['url']         =   $m->url;
           $menu[$m->ID]['children']    =   array();
       }
   }
   $submenu = array();
   foreach ($array_menu as $m) {
       if ($m->menu_item_parent) {
           $submenu[$m->ID] = array();
           $submenu[$m->ID]['ID']       =   $m->ID;
           $submenu[$m->ID]['title']    =   $m->title;
           $submenu[$m->ID]['url']  =   $m->url;
           $menu[$m->menu_item_parent]['children'][$m->ID] = $submenu[$m->ID];
       }
   }
   return $menu;
```

}

Comment: `$array_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($current_menu);` may be the problem; have you run a `var_dump($array_menu)` to make sure you're getting what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

The bug is not in this snippet of code. The problem is with how you call `wp_get_nav_menu_array`, wherever that happens. The $current_menu is likely something invalid, so `wp_get_nav_menu_items` returns `false`, and thus you get the error that you get.

You can see in user contributed notes an example of how to get a valid value for $current_menu https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/#user-contributed-notes

Comment: Can you give me a sample code to get $current menu?